# Abbreviating the year in ASP

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am working on a calendar application and I want to display the date such as: `mm/dd/yy`. The reason for this is because on mobile devices some of my dates are getting recognized as phone numbers when it is in `mm/dd/yyyy`. I couldn't find a VBScript function to accomplish this so I tried it with the following code:

```
listyear = Year(strlistdate)
listyearabbr = Right(listyear, 2)
strlistdate = Replace(strlistdate, listyear, listyearabbr)
```

Where strlistdate is the initial date returned from the database. I then display the date using `Response.write("<td>" &FormatDateTime(strlistdate,2)&"</td>")`

This didn't work and I was wondering if someone could give me a few pointers on how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: How exactly did it "not work"? And why would you manually format a date string only to pass that formatted string to a date formatting function? As long as `FormatDateTime()` recognizes `strlistdate` as a valid date, it will produce the same output, regardless of what format you applied before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is a good approach, because you'll end up returning the same date format for all locales, but you could do this:

```
response.write(Month(strlistdate) & "/" & Day(strlistdate) & "/" & Right(Year(strlistdate),2))
```

Anytime you use FormatDateTime, it will create a year based on the definition stored on the server.  If the server can be set to mm/dd/yy, then you can get the output you want without doing any of the above.

Also, look into the format function.  You should be able to do this: 
response.write(Format(strlistdate, "m/dd/y")

Answer (score 0):

You could try this idea. I haven't used date formatting for years. Instead I construct the date field like so...

```
strDay = Day(Date)
strMonth = Month(Date)
strYear = Year(Date)
strHours = Hour(Now)
strMins = Minute(Now)
strSecs = Second(Now())
    if len(strMonth) = 1 then
        strMonth = "0" & strMonth
    end if
    if len(strDay) = 1 then
        strDay = "0" & strDay
    end if
    if len(strHours) = 1 then
        strHours = "0" & strHours
    end if
    if len(strMins) = 1 then
        strMins = "0" & strMins
    end if
    if len(strSecs) = 1 then
        strSecs = "0" & strSecs
    end if

strDateAdded = strYear & "-" & strMonth & "-" & strDay
strDateAddedTime = strDateAdded & " " & strHours & ":" & strMins
```

Using this method you have complete control over the order and even when running your web app in different time zones, you still maintain DD/MM format... or whatever order you want such as MM-DD-YY (by reordering and trimming the year). Personally I prefer YYYY-MM-DD because sorting by ASC and DESC is a lot easier to work with, ie: easier to read because all rows will have the same number of characters like:

```
2013-04-01 03:15
2013-04-09 10:15
2013-04-22 07:15
2013-04-23 10:15
2013-04-23 10:60
2013-10-25 12:01
2013-10-25 12:59
```

Instead of:

```
2013-4-1 3:15
2013-4-9 10:15
2013-4-22 7:15
2013-4-23 10:15
2013-4-23 10:60
2013-10-25 12:1
2013-1-25 12:59
```